# Java policy file cannot assign permissions to a codebase jar

Tags: java, security, permissions, policy, codebase

I have written my java policy file to give allPermission to a jar say "xyz.jar"

```
grant codebase "file:lib/xyz.jar" {
  permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

But while executing the program I get a AccessControlException for a **property permission**. This property is set by a class in the jar.

While doing the policy debugging following are the entries:

```
policy: evaluate codesources:
    Policy CodeSource: (file:/C:/path/lib/xyz.jar <no signer certificates>)
    Active CodeSource: (file:/C:/path/lib/log4j-1.2.9.jar <no signer certificates>)
policy: evaluation (codesource) failed
```

and

```
policy: evaluate codesources:

    Policy CodeSource: (null <no signer certificates>)
    Active CodeSource: (file:/C:/path/lib/xyz.jar <no signer certificates>)

policy: evaluate principals:

    Policy Principals: [com.abc.MyLoginModule/principalA]
    Active Principals: []

policy: evaluation (principals) failed
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Try putting the full path to the jar file in your policy file. I'm not sure where it would be trying to find lib/xyz.jar relative to.

Comment: "Where am I going wrong?"  I would say at the very moment you decided to use policy files rather than digitally signing the code that needs to be trusted.  The (damn) tutorials focus far too much on policy files.  They are difficult for developers to get right, so no end user should be altering them.

Comment: For an applet I maintined a year ago that required an "AllPermission" policy file to run reports, we actually had to email them the policy file with instructions on where to put it.  It all felt truly wrong.  They ALWAYS messed it up.

Comment: @user53300 - Well the path is correct as shown in the debugging entries (did not mention the exact path in my query).

Comment: so did you ever get a solution for this? I am keen to know since I am facing a similar issue. Thanks.

Comment: @topgun_ivard if you have solution for this problem please share